# Prove that $\frac{1}{AM \cdot BN} + \frac{1}{BN \cdot CP} + \frac{1}{CP \cdot AM} \le \frac{4}{3(R - OI)^2}$.

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> $(O, R)$ is the circumscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$. $I \in \triangle ABC$. $AI$, $BI$ and $CI$ intersects $AB$, $BC$ and $CA$ respectively at $M$, $N$ and $P$. Prove that $$\large \frac{1}{AM \cdot BN} + \frac{1}{BN \cdot CP} + \frac{1}{CP \cdot AM} \le \frac{4}{3(R - OI)^2}$$

I have provided my own solution and I would be greatly appreciated if there are any other solutions, perhaps one involving trigonometry. I deeply apologise for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The last inequality is not true when I=O

Comment: Only when $I \equiv O$, right?

Comment: $I$ is an arbitrary point in the interior of the given $\Delta ABC$? (So possibly not the incenter...?!)

Comment: Also note that in the given inequality the RHS is not in the same "dimension" as the LHS. (If the lengths are measured in [m], then we have $[m]^{-2}$ versus $[m]^{-1}$. A square is missing in the RHS?

Comment: No. The problem is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

$$\frac{IM}{AM} + \frac{IN}{BN} + \frac{IP}{CP} = \frac{A_{CIB}}{A_{CAB}} + \frac{A_{AIC}}{A_{ABC}} + \frac{A_{BIA}}{A_{BCA}} = 1$$

where $A_m$ denotes the area of shape $m$.

$$\frac{AI}{AM} + \frac{BI}{BN} + \frac{CI}{CP} = 3 - \left(\frac{IM}{AM} + \frac{IN}{BN} + \frac{IP}{CP}\right) = 2$$

We have that $$\frac{1}{AM \cdot BN} + \frac{1}{BN \cdot CP} + \frac{1}{CP \cdot AM} \le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{AM} + \frac{1}{BN} + \frac{1}{CP}\right)^2$$

$$\le \frac{1}{3}\left[\left(\frac{AI}{AM}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{BI}{BN}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{CI}{CP}\right)^2\right]\left(\frac{1}{AI^2} + \frac{1}{BI^2} + \frac{1}{CI^2}\right)$$

(according to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)

However

$$\left(\frac{AI}{AM}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{BI}{BN}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{CI}{CP}\right)^2 \ge \dfrac{1}{3}\left(\frac{AI}{AM} + \frac{BI}{BN} + \frac{CI}{CP}\right)^2 = \frac{4}{3}$$

Now I just need to prove that

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{AI^2} + \frac{1}{BI^2} + \frac{1}{CI^2}\right) \le \frac{1}{(R - OI)^2}$$

which can be easily proven because

$$\left\{ \begin{align} AI \ge |AO - OI|\\ BI \ge |BO - OI|\\ CI \ge |CO - OI|\\ \end{align} \right. = |R - OI|$$

Comment: For the inequality after *However*, do you require $\le \frac{4}{3}$ rather than $\ge \frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: In detail, you require $\left(\frac{AI}{AM}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{BI}{BN}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{CI}{CP}\right)^2 \le \frac{4}{3}$
and $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{AI^2} + \frac{1}{BI^2} + \frac{1}{CI^2}\right) \le \frac{1}{(R - OI)^2}$
to obtain the desired result. However, you just prove 
$\left(\frac{AI}{AM}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{BI}{BN}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{CI}{CP}\right)^2 \ge \frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: If you have another solution, could you please post it up here?

Comment: I have not yet come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments the inequality:
$$\large \frac{1}{AM \cdot BN} + \frac{1}{BN \cdot CP} + \frac{1}{CP \cdot AM} \le \frac{4}{3(R - OI)}$$
Is not homogeneous and therefore cannot be correct. Take any triangle and any point and even if the given inequality is satisfied fot this configuration then after scaling it by $a$ for sufficiently small $a$ it will stop being correct. But somehow you have managed to convert it to homogeneous inequality:
$$\frac{1}{AI} + \frac{1}{BI} + \frac{1}{CI} \le \frac{2}{R - OI}$$
Which still seems not to be true. And even if it was you obtained it by means of this wrong inequality (no surprise since homogeneous and non-homogeneous inequalities can't be equivalent):
$$\left(\frac{1}{AM} + \frac{1}{BN} + \frac{1}{CP}\right)^2 \le \left(\frac{AI}{AM} + \frac{BI}{BN} + \frac{CI}{CP}\right)\left(\frac{1}{AI} + \frac{1}{BI} + \frac{1}{CI}\right)$$
Which is a flawed application of CS inequality. The correct application is:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{AM}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{BN}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{CP}}\right)^2 \le \left(\frac{AI}{AM} + \frac{BI}{BN} + \frac{CI}{CP}\right)\left(\frac{1}{AI} + \frac{1}{BI} + \frac{1}{CI}\right)$$

Comment: Could you now proceed with the question?

Comment: I have fixed the question accordingly, it is now $\dfrac{4}{3(R - OI)^2}$ instead of $\dfrac{4}{3(R - OI)}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong.

Indeed, let $\Delta A'B'C'\sim\Delta ABC$ such that $\frac{A'B'}{AB}=\epsilon.$

Thus, if your inequality is true, so we have $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{A'M'\cdot B'N'}\leq\frac{4}{3(R'-O'I')}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{AM\cdot BN}\leq\frac{4}{3(R-OI)},$$ which is wrong for $\epsilon\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: So what changes could be made to make the inequality correct (and homogeneous)?